# property change lister does not invoke the method propertychangeevent

Tags: java, swing, propertychangelistener

Below is my code regarding property change. If I use this code,
`public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)` will be called properly.

```
public void setWeekDate(Date weekDate) {        
   firePropertyChange("weekDate", this.weekDate, this.weekDate = weekDate);     
}
```

But if I use below code `public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)` will not be 
called.

```
public void setWeekDate(Date weekDate) {
    this.weekDate = weekDate;   
    firePropertyChange("weekDate", this.weekDate, weekDate);
}
```

could anyone tell me whats wrong with the above code?

Comment: Please provide method `firePropertyChange`.

Comment: Have you debugged whether the code steps into the method?

Answer (score 2):

In the second instance, you provide the same value twice. I'm guessing firePropertyChange does nothing if the value didn't actually change. Try this:

```
public void setWeekDate(Date weekDate) {
    Date oldValue = this.weekDate;
    this.weekDate = weekDate;   
    firePropertyChange("weekDate", oldValue, this.weekDate);
}
```

Comment: sorry it is my mistake. I have modified the code.I will try your code as well thank you..

Comment: take a look at the code for Component.  It does in fact check if the two objects are the same: if (changeSupport == null ||(oldValue != null && newValue != null && oldValue.equals(newValue))) {
                return;
            }

Comment: @akf: It was never specified this is an instance of a Java Component though. The firePropertyChange could be a custom made method.

Comment: @DavidtenHove Almost all code in the JDK uses the same convention, which is documented in then `PropertyChangeSupport` class.